# How can I prove this formula: $\sum_{a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_m\le n}\prod_{i=1}^ma_i=\binom{n+m}{2m}$?

Tags: summation, combinations, binomial-coefficients, products

Take $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_m$ balls sequentially from a box of n balls, and  you don't have to take all of them. It is guaranteed that $1\le m\le n$.

Denote the product of $a_1,a_2,\cdots ,a_m$ as $\prod_{i=1}^ma_i$ .

Prove that $\binom{n+m}{2m}=\frac{(n+m)!}{(2m)!(n-m)!}$ is the sum of  $\prod_{i=1}^ma_i$ for all possible $a_1,a_2,\cdots ,a_m$ sequences. That is to prove

$$
\sum_{a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_m\le n}\prod_{i=1}^ma_i=\binom{n+m}{2m}
$$

where $a_1,a_2,\cdots ,a_m$ and $m, n$ are all positive integers, and $m \le n$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be proven by induction over $m$. The base case is $m = 1$ and is obvious. To establish $m + 1$ given $m$ one only needs to check that (verify this!)
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-m} k \binom{n + m - k}{2m} = \binom{n + m + 1}{2m + 2}. 
$$
(Note that above $k$ indicates the value of $a_{m+1}$ and the coefficient arises from the induction hypothesis at $m$.)

To establish the identity above, expand.
Re-indexing the sum, we find (check!)
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-m} k \binom{n + m - k}{2m} = \sum_{j=1}^{n-m} \binom{2m + (n - m -j) + 1}{2m + 1} = \sum_{j=0}^{n-m - 1} \binom{2m + 1 + j}{2m + 1} = \binom{n +m + 1}{2m +2}. 
$$
This proves the claim. Above, we have repeatedly used the [rising sum identity for binomial coefficients.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rising_Sum_of_Binomial_Coefficients)

Comment: I have omitted some details above intentionally: you should check that the displayed equation is indeed sufficient to establish the claim for $m + 1$, and that the first equality in the second equation holds.

Comment: Thanks for your succinct proof, but the last step should be 
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n-m-1}\binom{2m+1+j}{2m+1}=\binom{n+m+1}{2m+2}.
$$
right?

Comment: Indeed, fixed above.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Special_cases) $(1-z)^{-m-1}=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\binom{m+n}{m}z^n$ and generating functions.
\begin{align}
S_{m,n}&:=\sum_{\substack{a_1,\ \dots,\ a_m>0\\a_1+\dots+a_m\leqslant n}}\prod_{k=1}^m a_k;
\\\sum_{n\geqslant m}S_{m,n}z^n&=\sum_{n\geqslant m}\sum_{\substack{a_1,\ \dots,\ a_m>0\\a_1+\dots+a_m\leqslant n}}z^n\prod_{k=1}^m a_k
\\&=\sum_{a_1,\ \dots,\ a_m>0}\sum_{n\geqslant a_1+\dots+a_m}z^n\prod_{k=1}^m a_k
\\&=\sum_{a_1,\ \dots,\ a_m>0}\frac{z^{a_1+\dots+a_m}}{1-z}\prod_{k=1}^m a_k
\\&=\frac1{1-z}\left(\sum_{a>0}^\infty az^a\right)^m=\frac{z^m}{(1-z)^{2m+1}}
\\&=z^m\sum_{k\geqslant 0}\binom{2m+k}{2m}z^k=\sum_{n\geqslant m}\binom{m+n}{2m}z^n.
\end{align}